\mathbb{\gamma} and \mathbb{\pi} are swapped in ConTeXt
In ConTeXt, \mathbb{\gamma} outputs a pi symbol, while \mathbb{\pi} outputs a gamma. This seems to be a ConTeXt issue, not font-related. What should I do?
\startTEXpage[offset=5pt]
  \m{\mathbb{\gamma\pi}}
\stopTEXpage



In math-map.lmt, around line 416-418, it should read
    lcgreek   = { -- gamma pi
        [0x03B3]=0x0213D, [0x03C0]=0x0213C,
    },

You need to regenerate your formats context --make. Doing so, your file gives me:

I will send the corrected file to Hans.

The same error is found in MkIV's math-map.lua, at lines 406-408.

Yes, thanks, Hans is aware and it will get fixed in the next version.
